# download pdf files with wget

Tags: wget

I want to download the pdf file in [this link](http://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.250402), but

`wget 'http://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.250402'`

will not help. What should I do?

Edit:

Some messages are following:

1. It turns to a verification page when open a link as this at first time, then it will always show a pdf file.
2. Before I use wget to download it I have already finished the verification.
3. My university has the access to this journals without login.

Comment: is a login required to access the pdf? I don't see it at the link you provided

Comment: @lese Login is not required, but a verification is needed when open a link like that at the first time.

Answer (score 1):

If an http authentication is required in order to reach the url, there are some of `wget` parameters that may interest you, `wget --help` will provide the info I'm referring to :

> ```
>    --auth-no-challenge     send Basic HTTP authentication information
>                            without first waiting for the server's
>                            challenge.
>    --http-user=USER        set http user to USER.
>    --http-password=PASS    set http password to PASS.
> ```

said that, if this is your real problem, using the above parameters should solve it:

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --http-user="username" --http-password="password" "url_to_your_pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry but I don't see any pdf under the link you posted.

to be more specific, this is not a pdf:

```
  http://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.250402
```

it should be something like:

```
  http://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.250402.pdf
```

Comment: if you do not provide an answer, you should post a comment, not am Answer : )

Comment: that is an answer actually:-)

Comment: I'm not sure of that

Comment: @lese; your answer is correct and complete of course, but the user did not asked for user/passwd auth based pdf downloads, even though I could see that from the link. In my opinion, people has to learn how to post questions properly, otherwise the quality of forum will deteriorate and people with quality will participate less. As you can see I am pretty new but I am already loosing motivation (not because of you to be clear)for the meaningless posts along with response. I wonder how long I will survive. the forum needs to be better regulated in terms of quality, if you know what I mean. thanks

Comment: I didn't want to offend you, I just don't think it is a problem of wrong url, but of authentication blocking the wget. Said that, I think you are right, My answer(and I think also your one :) is based on a supposition because the question quality is low. I agree with you, people has to learn to ask questions but it is not as easy as much people think. The real question could be , should I answer if question quality is low but I feel to understand the problem maybe because I already faced it? maybe the answer to this question is no, I should not answer and just flag the question

Comment: no offence at all, all good:-)